# How do i write the code in protractor form?

Tags: protractor

This is my html code. now I wan to use the locator to locate the value in span.

```
 <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">
                <span>/&nbsp;{{selectedPrefix.id}}&nbsp;</span>
```

Is this the correct way?

```
static SUBNET_CLASS = element.all(by.exactBinding('/&nbsp;{{selectedPrefix.id}}&nbsp;'));
```

Please give me some hint how to change it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `css` as like below

```
static SUBNET_CLASS = element.all(by.css('button.btn.btn-default.dropdown-toggle>span'));
```

Hope it helps you